# jq: using type in the format file

Tags: bash, jq

I got multiple json files with different format.

```
**Format_1**:

{
  "numbers":[
   "0",
   "1",
   "2"
  ]
}

**Format_2**:

{
  "numbers":[
   "0"
  ]
}
```

If it is an array, I would like to get the 2nd element in the array and if it is not, just return the element available.

```
cat Format_1 | jq '.numbers' | jq 'if type=="array" then '.[2]' else '.' end'
```

The above command works fine and give me the **output** 1

```
cat Format_2 | jq '.numbers' | jq 'if type=="array" then '.[2]' else '.' end'
```

The above command give me the **output 0**.

When I try to put the above in a format file and pass it to jq, i get syntax error

```
**Format_File**:

{
   numbers : .numbers | 'if type=="array" then '.[2]' else '.' end'
}
```

**command**:

```
cat Format_1 | jq -f Format_file -c
```

***jq: error: syntax error, unexpected end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 11:
        numbers  : .numbers | 'if type=="array" then '.[2]' else '.' end',***

Can someone help me with the syntax of the format file with IF Statement please?

Comment: What's with all the extra quotes? `'.'` or `'.[2]'` are wrong -- it's just `.`, or `.[2]`. Same issue throughout your code.

Comment: Likewise, no quotes around the `if` block as a whole either.

Comment: (btw, it's not a "format file", it's a jq script).

Comment: Thanks Charles for the comments. I have changed the jq script to the below   

{
   numbers : .numbers | if type==array then .[2] else . end
} still getting syntax error

Comment: That said, `numbers` is an array in both cases -- it's just an array of length 1 in the first.

Comment: BTW, better to run `jq -f file.jq input.json`, without all the `cat`. Running `cat input | somecommand` starts an extra, separate `cat` process, and gives `somecommand` only a FIFO handle which can be read exactly once; whereas `somecommand <input` or (if supported) `somecommand input` provides a "real" file handle which can be reread, seek'd, inspected for size, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jq` script correctly works (giving output of `{"numbers": "2"}`), if written as follows:

```
{
   numbers: (.numbers | if type=="array" then .[2] else . end)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked and also removed the cat <filename> from the script.

Answer (score 0):

> If it is an array, I would like to get the 2nd element in the array and if it is not, just return the element available.

1. If by "2nd element" you mean the second element, you would use 1 as the array index, since jq has a 0 as its "index origin".
2. Both of your two examples (Format_1 and Format_2) have arrays as the value of `.numbers`, but if your requirement is as stated, with the interpretation of "2nd" as "second", a suitable jq filter would seem to be:

   .numbers | if type == "array" then .[1] else . end

Your program is so short that you could simply run it as follows:

```
jq -c '.numbers | if type == "array" then .[1] else . end' Format_{1,2}
```

3. If you want to place your jq program in a file, then it is good practice to use a filetype of "jq" (i.e. name the file so that it ends with ".jq"). Using `Format_file.jq` as the file name, you could use the following invocation:

   jq -f Format_file.jq -c Format_1 Format_2

Note the avoidance of `cat`.

4. In none of your examples is it necessary or wise to use a pipeline with more than one invocation of jq.

If you want the output to look like the input but with the value of the "numbers" key to be altered as per the above, you could simply replace '=`by`|=`:

```
 .numbers |= if type == "array" then .[1] else . end
```